# Updating data between views with standard user defaults

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a table view (view 1) with some cells that when selected let's the user configure some app settings on another view (view 2). This process is managed by a navigationcontroller, and the settings are always stored and retrieved from the standard user defaults.

The problem starts as one of those properties is displayed on view 1 on the detail text label of a cell, and is edited on view2 in a text label.

If the user is in the process of editing the attribute, on view 2, on the text label and he presses the back button to return to view 1, it's cell's detail Text Label isn't immediately updated. (on exiting the view, I have saved the data on the user defaults  and forced a synchronize, and when loading the view 1 I forced the tableview to reload data)

The detail text label it's only updated after forcing a reloadData on the tableView 0.4s after the view appeared on the iPhone Simulator, and not before. This could be a little jarring for a user.

Does anyone has better solution? The perfect solution would be simple to implement
and instantaneous.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the "0.4s" delay coming from?

Comment: Trial and error... If I make the refresh 0.3s (or even 0.35s) after the view is displayed, the new data will not show up. I guess this could be the time that the user defaults needs to save state... However it was done on the simulator on my computer (I have haven't had the time to test on a ios device or other computer, but I'm curious to know if it changes)

Comment: If you call `synchronize` on your defaults object, the update should be immediate.

Comment: I have tried that in various points (after saving the attribute, exiting the view 2, displaying view 1) but only after calling synchronize and delaying the tableview reload data in 0.4s this worked. Also I have been toying with a iPhone 3GS and the delay is 0.5s... So changes with the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to pass the changed information from view 2 to view 1 through a delegate protocol or some other form of communication while the data is being saved to the defaults. If for some reason your saving to the NSUserDefaults failed then this would break but it should fix your lag problem.

Comment: That could be a bit messy. This information will be send on another channel to view 1 and it should be updated. However at the same time this view is preparing to be displayed again and it will do a tableview reloadData with the user defaults values (there are some other attributes that could have been changed that should be updated...)

Comment: So your biggest problem is that your refresh just has to happen a little later (.4s for you)? Assuming I understand your problem I would perform the saving of the default's on a separate thread and when it is done synchronizing I'd call do the navigation to the previous view or do the necessary refresh. Again this is assuming I understanding what you want to do.

Comment: The problem it's that delay will make the detail label have changes **after** the view has loaded and be displayed. That can be annoying for the user and make the app appear to be a little sloppy...

Comment: Yeah I understand. It seems you might just have to pick the best option. Another thing you can do is throw an activity indicator up there. If it is normally very fast to save then it will give the impression that you are doing some work and it will feel fast where as now it feels like there is a hiccup.

Comment: Yes that could be cool, I will try that later if an idea that I have now doesn't pan out. (changing the back button on view 2 to put a delay on loading view 1)